# this code is about SSN and i need to see errors in it because its for a college project and i can't do it

Tags: c++

Please help me with the errors that come up with the code. for example if you enter 1650712999999 it should display male 65.07.12 and 1 at the start represents male and 2 at the start represents female and then the birthdate YY.MM.DD and the other numbers are irrelevant

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    int s,d,m,y;
    cout << "Enter your SSN" << endl;
    cin>>n;
    s=0;
    y=0;
    m=0;
    d=0;
    if((n <= 2991231999999) && (n >= 1000101000000))
    {

        n=n/1000000 %10;
        s=n/1000000 %10;
        y=(n/100000 %10 *10)+(n/10000 %10);
        m=(n/1000 %10 *10)+ (n/100 %10);
        d=(n/10 %10 *10) + (n %10);
        if
       {

            s=1
            cout<<"male "<<y<<"."<<m<<"."<<d;
         else
            cout<<"female "<<y<<"."<<m<<"."<<d;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid SSN" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you learned using your debugger?  And why does your second `if` look nothing like your first `if`?

Comment: There is no condition after `if` in line 24 (or 23). (The condition is the expression in parentheses used to decide whether to continue in the following statement or the (optional) `else` statement.)

Comment: @Scheff - Which is why I asked about the second `if`, since that's where it's failing to compile.

Comment: 'please help me' is not a suitable question for this site. Ask **specific** questions about your task and you should get some help.

Comment: Also a semicolon is missing after `s=1`.

Comment: ok thank you for all the comments i was so dumb that i didn't put the condition in semicolons maybe that's because i'm abegginer and i'm not used to see the mistakes i resolved the problem now all it's good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `%10` in `n=n/1000000 %10;` is deleting required data, so you should remove that.
- There are no condition for the inner `if` statement, so you have to add that.
- Stray `s=1` should be removed because lack of semicolon after that will lead to compile error.
- Some curly braces are missing around the inner `if` statement, so you have to add that.
- You should use [`std::setw`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iomanip/setw.html) and [`std::setfill`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iomanip/setfill.html) to get `65.07.12` instead of `65.7.12`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // add this to use setw() and setfill()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int n;
    int s,d,m,y;
    cout << "Enter your SSN" << endl;
    cin>>n;
    s=0;
    y=0;
    m=0;
    d=0;
    if((n <= 2991231999999) && (n >= 1000101000000))
    {

        n=n/1000000; // remove %10
        s=n/1000000 %10;
        y=(n/100000 %10 *10)+(n/10000 %10);
        m=(n/1000 %10 *10)+ (n/100 %10);
        d=(n/10 %10 *10) + (n %10);
        cout << setfill('0'); // add this
        if (s == 1) // add condition
       {
            // remove stray s=1
            cout<<"male "<<setw(2)<<y<<"."<<setw(2)<<m<<"."<<setw(2)<<d; // add setw()
         } // add this
         else
         { // add this
            cout<<"female "<<setw(2)<<y<<"."<<setw(2)<<m<<"."<<setw(2)<<d; // add setw()
       }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid SSN" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```